# Object does not support property or method but shows in intellisense

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, popup

I'm trying to display a popup in my web application. I've downloaded a really nice java script library called [bPopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) and added a script reference to the page but when I run the application I get the following error:

[image]

I've made sure that the script reference for bPopup is added after the script reference for jQuery. I also thought that maybe the version of jQuery I'm using (jquery-1.8.2.js) is unsupported so I've created a WebForms application and tried doing the popup there and it works but in the MVC 4.0 application I'm getting the above mentioned error. Also when I type $("#elementId") and press **.** I can see bPopup in intellisense but for some reason when I try call it in document.ready() I get the error.

**Script references in the view:**

```
<link href="../../Content/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.bpopup-0.9.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#popup').bPopup();
    });
</script>
```

**HTML for popup:**

```
<div id="popup">
    Content of popup
</div>
```

Comment: Please check in javascript debug console if there are any errors

Comment: can you add the bpopup.js after the knockout.js and check if it actually loads?

Comment: Thanks I've tried that @Abhidev, still getting the same error

Comment: is the bPopup.js being loaded?

Comment: How can I check if it's being loaded? I thought if you add a script reference to the head section of your page and if you can see the methods from the .js file then that means it's loaded?

Comment: open your page in a browser like chrome, then check the network tab as your page loads, you should see bpopup in there

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve this issue is to use [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
 $.getScript("../../Scripts/jquery.bpopup-0.9.4.min.js", function () {
        $('#popup').bPopup({
            easing: 'easeOutBack', //uses jQuery easing plugin
            speed: 800,
            transition: 'slideDown'
        });
    });
```

I would still like to know why the script is not loading even though I added a reference to the .js file until then will just stick to this work around